# Publish Meteor users who belong to the same organization as the logged in user?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections, publish

I'm trying to create a page that shows all the users in the db that belong to my same organization.

My users are stored as follows:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: email,
    password: password,
    profile:{
        firstName: first,
        lastName: last,
        type: "Member",
        organization: organization,
        created: date
    }
});
```

I know I have to publish the users to my user list component, and i'm struggling figuring out how to publish only the users whose profile.organization matches the logged in users profile.orgainzation.

This returns all users as it should, I got that far:

```
return Meteor.users.find();
```

I tried using the next block of code you see here, but it doesn't work, probably for multiple reasons, it even throws an error saying I can't use Meteor.user() server side, that I have to use this.user()... but that didn't work either:

```
return Meteor.users.find({

    profile:{
        organiztion: Meteor.user().profile.organization
    }

});
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work (untested). This is a server-side function.

```
Meteor.publish("organizationUsers", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId); 
    var org = user.profile.organization; 
    return Meteor.users.find({'profile.organization': org});
  }
});
```

Client side, you can filter the users you want (and exclude the current user) with:

```
Meteor.users.find({'profile.organization': org, '_id' : {$not : Meteor.userId()}});
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thanks so much, the server-side worked. I really wanted to limit it server side so that someone else in another organization couldn't get access (if they wanted to) to users from a different organization.